# Mobile home circuit breaker is not working

Tags: electrical

Hi I had changes the outlets and lights on the one breaker and I am still not getting power to any of the rooms. I also replaced the breaker itself to see if that was the problem. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We need more information: how did this problem start? What exactly is wrong? What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Can you post photos of what's going on?

Comment: Move the breaker in question to a different position in the breaker box and see if you get power. Sounds like you could have a dead spot on one of the bus's. if you do have a dead spot, it's best to replace the box. If you don't want to replace it, you will have to find a way to avoid using that spot on the bus.

Comment: How do you know there's no power?  Are you checking the wires themselves with a meter?

Comment: A common fault in mobile homes: Beneath your mobile home, the wires connect by a fusable splice. Often these splices will simply disconnect themselves, burn up, blow the fuse, or otherwise wear down. With a wire tracer (wire probe, wire tracker), you can trace the circuit from your panel to under the home to see if that junction is the cause of your loss of power. Troubleshooting can become tedious, so if you plan to do this yourself, I recommend following a guide on efficient methods, starting at the panel and verifying your way to the outlets.